# Monitor Service with Performance Monitor

Tags: performance, service, monitor

There are a lot of articles on how to use the performance monitoring tools built into windows with c# code... Im NOT looking for that.

Im looking for a way to ***list*** my own, self-built c# service, in the server performance monitor so when I go there on the server it says:

**MyService**: Number of *foo* or number of *bar/sec*

And then can do live monitoring and watch the foo and bar (whatever they are, like number of threads etc etc) go up and down.

I have in the past tied into the "EventLog" class and reported errors to the system log, now how do I make my service "monitor-able".

Comment: Do you mean to check a list of outputs as a thread? If so, try [SeaLion](http://sealion.com). You can add any command you wish and see the outputs on a timeline. Works for linux only.

Comment: Hi Kevin, no i mean, how do i publish my own values to "PerfMon".

Comment: http://www.benday.com/2011/12/17/how-to-create-custom-performance-monitor-perfmon-counters/